# Is it correct to say "does anyone have related reference?"

Tags: grammar, differences

> Does anyone have related reference?

Is the above sentence correct?

Or should it be written:

> Have anyone related reference?

What is the difference between these two sentences?

Comment: Before you ask your questions, make sure your questions are suitable on this site, please. You may like to have a look at [this site.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Does anyone have a related reference?* Refers to any related reference.

*Does anyone have the related reference?* Refers to a specific (definite) related reference.

See [Using articles](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/).

**EDIT**

*Has anyone a related reference?* Has is singular.